# android absolute layout

Tags: android, layout, absolute

I have a complex timetable to layout using `TextViews`. I see that absolute layout has been depreciated. Now i know it is "bad practice" but i have a well formed screen metrics class that will adjust everything in relation to screen size/density etc.

If i cannot use absolute layout, then how can i tell the `TextView` I want it so much left and top? (like in HTML using an absolute position)?

I want to do this programmatically not using XML. Is this possible or do i have to use a `WebView` or canvas?

EDIT::

```
    void positionView (TextView v, int x, int y, int w, int h){
    final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lpt = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);//v.getLayoutParams();
    //lpt.setMargins(x,y,x+w,y+h);
    lpt.height=h;
    lpt.width=w;
    lpt.topMargin=y;
    lpt.leftMargin=x;
    v.setLayoutParams(lpt);

}
```

This is the method i am calling from this quick testcode:

```
        ScrollView dayViewContainer = new ScrollView(context);
    dayViewContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    FrameLayout dayView = new FrameLayout(context);
    dayView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    dayView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00)
    int lineHeight = 60;

    for(int i =0;i<11 ;i++){
        TextView hourView = new TextView(context);
        hourView.setText(""+i+":00");
         BrScreenMetrics.getScreenWidthPX()-20, lineHeight);
        positionView(hourView, 50, i*lineHeight, BrScreenMetrics.getScreenWidthPX()-20, lineHeight);
        dayView.addView(hourView);
        }

    dayViewContainer.addView(dayView);
    addView(dayViewContainer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it programmatically by using the following code..

```
TextView title = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.default_panel_title))
final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lpt =(MarginLayoutParams)title.getLayoutParams();

lpt.setMargins(0,lpt.topMargin,lpt.rightMargin,lpt.bottomMargin);

title.setLayoutParams(lpt);
```

Comment: This code that @Sujit posted will work great for you, and you can consider using FrameLayout as the alternative for absolute layout. you can set margins with it starting from top left and the views placed inside a frameLayout aren't dependent on eachother. they are one on top of another, so they can overlap be placed wherever you want etc.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. I created a frameview and added the margins to the views but they just stay at 0,0. I may need to use a webview as i have already wasted a day on this already :(
I cannot understand why they have depreciated absolute layout because it does exactly what i want, and when calculated using the screen metrics works fine on different devices.

Answer (score 1):

Ok after a whole 24 hours of headscratching i finally came up with an answer for myself and anyone else :D
Thanks to everyone, your input certainly put me in right direction!

Basically margins in framelayout DO NOT WORK properly unless i am missing something. So what i have done is have to extend a fully expanded linear layout with the required view margined inside it.

For example:

```
public class BrPositionableTextView extends LinearLayout{

TextView text ;

public BrPositionableTextView(Context context, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    super(context);

    setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    text = new TextView(context);
    text.setHeight(h);
    text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL); 
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
    params.height = h;
    params.width = w;
    addView(text, params);
}

/**
 * @return the text
 */
public String getText() {
    return text.getText().toString();
}

/**
 * @param text the text to set
 */
public void setText(String text) {
    this.text.setText(text);
}

public void setMargins(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    //not tested, may need to recreate textview...
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(x, y, x+w, y+h);
    text.setLayoutParams(params);
}

public void setBackgroundColor(int color)
{
    text.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

}

This can then be added to the FrameLayout and will display the view in the right position.

Examples:

```
        ScrollView dayViewContainer = new ScrollView(context);
    dayViewContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    FrameLayout dayView = new FrameLayout(context);
    dayView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    dayView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF005000);
    dayView.setMinimumHeight(BrScreenMetrics.getScreenHeightMinusStatusBar());
    dayView.setMinimumWidth(BrScreenMetrics.getScreenWidthPX());
    int lineHeight = 60;

    for(int i =0;i<11 ;i++){
        BrPositionableTextView hourView = new BrPositionableTextView(
                context, 
                8, 
                i*lineHeight, 
                80, 
                lineHeight);

        hourView.setText(""+(i+7)+":00");

        dayView.addView(hourView);
        BrPositionableSeparator separator = new BrPositionableSeparator(
                context, 
                80, 
                (i*lineHeight)+((int)(lineHeight*0.5f)), 
                BrScreenMetrics.getScreenWidthPX()-117, 
                1);

        separator.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        dayView.addView(separator);

    }
    BrPositionableTextView bigassBox= new BrPositionableTextView(context, 100,200,300,500);
    bigassBox.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000FF);
    dayView.addView(bigassBox);

    dayViewContainer.addView(dayView);
    addView(dayViewContainer);
}
```